# In numpy, how to quikly find the index of the elements of a 1D ndarray `b` in another 1D ndarray `a`?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 1D ndarray `a` which contains many integers and they are not repeated, and `b` is another 1D ndarray which also contains many integers (may repeated) and these integers are the elements of `a`. I want to quikly find the location of the elements of `b` in `a`, how to do it?

Here is an example

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1000, 999, 82, 31], dtype=np.int_)
b = np.array([31, 31, 82, 999, 999], dtype=np.int_)
# and the indexing array should be
I = np.array([3, 3, 2, 1, 1])
```

Notice that, the size of `a` and `b` maybe very big.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
np.where()
```

something like this

```
for i in b:
    print(np.where(a == i))
```

Comment: It is not efficient. The size of `b` maybe very bigger.